# Inconsistent Display of Array Property in Bot Framework Composer: Direct vs. Concatenated Output

Tags: botframework

I am not sure how this crept out of no where.

I grab the user's response via  `= turn.activity.text`

I set an **array ** property to user.inputData

> [
> {
> "role": "user",
> "content": "${turn.activity.text}"
> }
> ]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIwqk.png)

Prior to a few days ago, step Send a Response: ${user.inputData} showed

> [ { "role": "user", "content": "test" } ]

now the step Send a Response shows:

> { "lgType": "Activity", "text": [ { "role": "user", "content": "test" } ] }

however if I concatenate in step Send a Response: `input is ${user.inputData}`  then it display correctly

> the input is [ { "role": "user", "content": "test" } ]

It seems like the Bot Framework Composer is interpreting ${user.inputData} differently now. The new output format is treating user.inputData as an object with properties lgType and text, where text holds my array. Did the template engine change in processing expressions?

I attempted to display user.inputData in two ways: directly and by concatenating it with a string. When displayed directly, I received an output showing the object with its properties ({ "lgType": "Activity", "text": [array] }). However, when I concatenated user.inputData with a string (e.g., input is ${user.inputData}), it displayed the **array as expected**, without the object properties. I was expecting consistent behavior in both cases, where user.inputData would simply display the array.

Comment: Did this start after a change in the SDK version of the bot? What version(s) is/was it running?

Comment: It started several days ago.  I have since fixed my Flask Endpoint to extract the message from text key.    I am using Version:  2.1.2
Electron: 8.2.4
Chrome: 80.0.3987.165
NodeJS: 12.13.0
V8: 8.0.426.27-electron.0

I was advised that issue was due to an update in the template engine used by the Bot Framework Composer.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce. Looks like there's other ways this may surface. Looks like a bug. Follow [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/9692).